# Segmentation fault occuring with zero-length array

Tags: c, memory

I have this linked list node struct that's using a zero-length array for storing memory:

```
typedef struct s_list
{
    size_t          *list_size;
    struct s_list   *prev;
    struct s_list   *next;
    size_t          size;
    char            data[0];
}   t_list;
```

(`list_size` is a pointer containing the size of the total list)

And I'm using this function to allocate a new node:

```
static t_list   *lst_new_element(void *data, size_t size)
{
    t_list  *new_element;

    new_element = malloc(sizeof(t_list) + size);
    if (!new_element)
        return (NULL);
    new_element->size = size;
    memcpy(new_element->data, data, size); // <--- Segfault occurs here
    return (new_element);
}
```

So the segmentation fault occurs in the memcpy, but I don't understand why because I allocate `sizeof(t_list) + size` bytes so this should be enough to do a `memcpy(size)` on data.
The segfault occured with this call: `lst_new_element((void *)atoll(argv[1]), sizeof(long long))` (`argv[1]` is `5`)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does `5` (`argv[1]`) represents a valid address to read in your environment? (For example, user binaries in [xv6](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public) will allow that)

Comment: `argv[1]` is `"5"` (it's written in the post)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I'm using [zero-length arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html#:~:text=6.18%20Arrays%20of%20Length%20Zero,for%20a%20variable%2Dlength%20object%3A&text=Accessing%20elements%20of%20zero%2Dlength,undefined%20and%20may%20be%20diagnosed.)

Comment: `atoll` doesn't return a pointer but a value.

Comment: Not sure but... for flexible array members, I write `[]` - not `[0]`

Comment: @4386427 [] is standard C, [0] is an obsolete non-standard gcc extension.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes, I know that, But what I want to do is copy the value no matter what data type it is, with memcpy, not just storing the pointer, I already did that before and had no problem with it

Comment: C is a weakly typed language. It is up to the programmer to write code which makes sense. Assign your atoll() result to a variable and call with the address of that variable: `long value = atoll(argv[1]); lst_new_element(&value, sizeof(value));`

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for info - I didn't know that

Comment: @Lundin [0] works with all C versions, but [] works only since C99, that's why I'm using [0], but are you sure it is obsolete ?

Comment: @BitTickler By doing this it would copy the address of the pointer, and I don't want that, I want to duplicate the data EDIT: nope you're right my bad, I don't know why I thought that x)

Comment: @BitTickler Well if not for the cast to void*, the compiler would have caught the bug. So C is "strongly enough" typed. Why we should be very careful with pointer casts, they are often wrong.

Comment: @Fayeure Yes there's no sense in using non-standard extensions when flexible array members got standardized in C99. The reason why this feature was added to the language was because gcc zero-length arrays acted as a "sandbox" for the new feature prior standardization.

Comment: @Fayeure gcc has not been the first c compiler supporting zero length arrays. Even in the olden days, having such an array as a last member in a struct was a common idiom. I suppose it is about as old as `realloc()`. They kind of go in pairs for many use cases.

Comment: @BitTickler Rather, back in the days, people were using something like `char arr[1];` as last member, then wildly converting that into some pointer or accessing it out of bounds. This was known as "the struct hack" and was a common source of strange bugs and broken code. Afaik gcc invented zero-length arrays as a cure against "the struct hack", somewhere in the mid-90s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a `long long` value to your function as if it's a valid `void *`.  Your function then attempts to dereference that pointer (which in invalid) in an attempt to copy what it points to.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) leading to a crash.

You need to assign the return value of `atoll` to a local variable, then pass the address of that variable to the function.

```
long long val = atoll(argv[1]);
t_list *l = lst_new_element((&val, sizeof(long long));
```

Also, using a 0 length array as the last member of a struct is an extension many compilers use to implement a *flexible array member*.  The standard-compliant way of doing this is to leave the size blank.

```
typedef struct s_list
{
    size_t          *list_size;
    struct s_list   *prev;
    struct s_list   *next;
    size_t          size;
    char            data[];
}   t_list;
```

Comment: Oh yes, I don't know why but I thought it would copy the address of the pointer, I forgot how my own code worked x), thanks

Answer (score 2):

`(void *)atoll` You are converting a `long long` value to a pointer which is of course plain wrong. Instead store the results in a temporary variable and pass that one (by value or reference).

Also please note that `ato...` functions are semi-obsolete and dangerous, you should be using `strtoll` instead, which has better error handling.

In addition (not related to the crash), zero-length arrays is an obsolete non-standard feature of gcc since well over 20 years. You should be using standard C flexible array members instead. They work exactly the same, just change the code to: `char data[];`.

Answer (score 2):

For your function call you need an intemediate variable to store the converted value, for example:

```
long long llval = atoll(argv[1]);
lst_new_element(&llval, sizeof(long long));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) to allocate a temporally array to have the value be in the memory instead of using temporally variable as othe answers suggests.

```
lst_new_element((long long[]){ atoll(argv[1]) }, sizeof(long long));
```

Comment: Clever, but since the compiler will allocate an invisible variable, nothing is gained, except obfuscation  (downvote not by me).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Compound literals are simply another approach presented here.